# Geometry Nodes (3.0) Stable ID port is missing

Tags: geometry-nodes

There used to be the *Stable ID* socket on the *Distribute Points On Faces* node.
Where did it go? My instances are "jumping".

The manual says to use the *ID > Set ID Nodes*, but I cannot figure out where to initiate them in my nodeflow. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: can u show us your node tree or provide blend file?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, of course here is the nodetree. It's an example of dynamic proximity scaling.

SOLUTION: The problem was caused by the *RGB Curves* node - the clamping was too harsh so it caused the sudden jump in size.

[image: here´s the Nodetree. hope that helps.]